# Problem with Hibernate template

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, oracle10g

I use hibernate for save, update and delete data in my database, but I have some problems.

For example I have a request for save or update my data in database

```
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(client);
getHibernateTemplate().flush();
```

When I launch my server (TomCat) for the first and I save my data, all is okay, in my database I see my data.

If I delete the data and I run a new save of my client, it performs an Update rather than an Insert even though I have deleted the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the objects are in memory already and hibernate already persisted them. When the application starts, hiberante loads the objects in memory as they are needed (lazy fetching) if not defined otherwise. When an object changes **programatically**, hibernate persists the object to the database. You don't need to use `save()`, just `commit()`. `save` is just for new created objects, and `update()` is for re-attaching detached objects to a session.

You can't change the database data  without using hibernate and expect hibernate to realize that the database changed. You must change the data using hibernate `session` methods.

If you change the data not using hibernate and you want hibernate to reaload the object, use the `session.refresh()` method to reload the object into memory from the database. This way the changes in the database will be reflected in the object loaded in memory.

More info in [Chapter 10 of Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html)

Comment: Read this [kickstart guide](http://techtracer.com/2008/12/30/the-great-hibernate-tutorial-a-great-jump-start-for-beginners/)

Comment: Good explanation. If I have made some changes to the object programatically (like setting some property) and there are changes to the object directly on DB, how can I refresh the object without losing the property I have updated?

Comment: My answer was from 8 years ago. Probably you should check the behavior of current versions of Hibernate.